# Iframe scrolling on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, iframe, mobile, scroll

I've got the following code:

```
<td style="position: relative; height: 100%;">
    <div style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow-y:auto; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0">
        <iframe id="appView" src="" style="height: 101%"></iframe>
    </div>
</td>
```

I've managed to get my iframe to scroll on mobile devices, but only when the iframe is taller than the parent div, e.g. 101%. Now I have to do this only on mobile devices, to avoid double scrollbars on desktops, which is annoying.

Is there a cleaner solution? The iframe must not expand in height - which is default behaviour on mobile - as the content of the iframe must be constrained in height to trigger its own scrolling. CSS only.

Thanks!

Comment: Add the scroll bar in the media queries so that it will appear only on small deceives.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution, not further hacks. I'm hoping I won't have to force the iframe to be larger than the parent in order for it to scroll.

Comment: Am not sure but I feel media query would be only the solution to handle mobile devices. This is a standard procedure. Sorry if I was wrong.

Comment: The Iframe should always be scrollable (if its content exceeds its dimensions) whether or not its dimensions exceed its parents.  
So I guess the issue is in your markup. Could you provide more code or a fiddle to work with?